# Rhinoceros 5 bad mesh occurs when engraving letters on ring

Tags: 3d, mesh, rhino3d, opennurbs, rhinoceros

My problem is literally
polysurface engraving simple 10 letters engraving wont come out on mesh even its comes out its a bad mesh so I cant print out...
I tried on polysurface and then make it mesh didnt work
I tried made it mesh and then tried it didnt worked what should I do?
Is there any one can help me?

Comment: Well font is solid text and boolean extract from the shank then it makes it like triangle inside the letter mould bit side walls I don't know how tomput screenshot in here....

Answer (score 0):

Metehan, we'd love to help you out over on the Rhino forum - please log in at http://discourse.mcneel.com and post your question there. Please attach the Rhino 3DM file that contains the solid letters before you boolean them with the ring.

Chances are good that the letters themselves have some problems prior to the boolean union - this is often caused by poor font design (some fonts look great on screen, but are a mess when turned into real geometry).

We can tell you a lot more when we see the file.